# DC VS AC current in water

Tags: current

I know a live AC wire in water is dangerous because AC actively seeks an earth ground by any means. Will a completed closed DC circuit using something with a floating ground like a battery and higher voltage like 70+ pose the same threat if submerged fully? Or does the DC current in the system only go back to the battery ground since the system is closed and DC does not actively seek an earth ground?

Comment: Current "seeks" a way from high to low potential. It doesn't matter if it's AC or DC here.

Comment: they're both a safety issue. DC will add more issues with electrochemistry

Comment: You need to be clearer about the question. Are you worried about contact between exposed wiring and water? Or accidental breakdown (leaks) between insulated wiring and water? Or the effect of surrounding a completely insulated system with water? These are three different questions, and it also makes a difference whether the water is fresh (a poor conductor) or seawater (much better conductor). For example, DC is worse (electrochemical effects where water contacts wiring) but underwater AC transmission lines have unsustainably high losses from capacitance to conductive seawater.

Answer (score 2):

*Lightning* is caused by a separation of charges between the atmosphere and the earth. Therefore the current in *lightning* may be said to "seek" the earth.

However, in general, electricity "seeks" to return to its *source*, not the earth. That is, it "seeks" to flow in a closed loop or circuit. It may pass through the ground (or water) on its way back to its source, if the the ground (or water) provides a path which would complete a circuit loop. To complete a circuit loop through the ground, there must be *two* points of contact with the earth.

This is true of AC or DC.

Mains systems in the US have one wire (the neutral wire) "bonded" (i.e. connected) to earth. So, the earth may easily be part of a path which would complete a loop or circuit for mains power if an unintentional *second* point of contact is made between the mains "line" wire and earth.

A battery, may or may not be part of a circuit which has a point of contact with the earth or water. It all depends upon whether there are *two* points of contact.. Remember, electricity (other than static electricity or lightning) does not "seek" the ground, but "seeks" a route to complete a circuit.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly since the DC circuit is closed the water would have no affect on the path of the electricity?

Comment: @koolzr. Being "closed" is not the right way to think about it. Electricity does not only seek the path of least resistance, but _all_ paths. Current will be greater in the path of least resistance, but may still be harmful in other paths. What you need to look at is whether there is a circuit path through the water.

Answer (score 0):

Take a 9V battery and throw it in a lake. What happens?  The terminals corrode due to flow of current through the water between those terminals.  The battery may "last" 4 hours like this before being depleted.

Now solder a resistor and LED onto another battery and throw it into the lake.  What happens now?  The LED lights, and whatever path is available between the + and - still corrode. This will be at the terminals, along any exposed wiring, and at the LED.  Any powered, exposed metal corrodes. It lasts about 3 hours due to the additional LED current and additional corrosion current.

Now get another LED and battery, solder an anchor to one of the terminals (lets say the positive terminal), and throw it in.  What happens now?  The anchor sinks, rests on the bottom of the lake, and becomes an excellent (large) conductor for current to flow *anywhere from the battery negative terminal/wire/LED*.  That may last 2 hours.

Another one, with an anchor on each terminal, may only last 15 minutes.

Water is only slightly conductive (typically), so larger surface areas increase the amount of current that can flow.  Salt water is typically much more conductive than freshwater, due to the dissolved salt ions.

If a diver comes by and touches the LED, could they be shocked?  It depends. If they have an insulated hand (diver wetsuit) they would likely be fine, because the current can't get through the suit (insulator) into their body.  If bare-handed, they could possibly be shocked, the severity of which depends on many factors.

*Any route which could allow more current to flow to/from the battery terminals*, will shock the diver.  This means that even if the diver is swimming *above* the contraption and touches the negative terminal, their large size (and the large size of the anchor) will cause more current to flow, hence being shocked.

So for this reason (and to prevent corrosion), exposed AC/DC in water is never allowed.  Undersea power cabling goes through extensive measures to ensure the water never reaches the conductors inside.

Incidentally, this corrosion is actually the [electrolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis_of_water) or dis-association of water.  The water molecules, along with the dissolved minerals in the water and the metal of the conductors themselves, are re-arranged to form different compounds by the electric current. The by-products of electrolysis are generally undesired and could be unhealthy for marine life.

DC will cause discrete chemical changes at each conductor (such as one liberating only hydrogen gas while the other liberates only oxygen.)

AC, since it is repeatedly changing polarity, means that both conductors will liberate hydrogen *and* oxygen.  So there are technical differences between DC and AC in water, but both could shock equally well.

Finally, please don't test this in a fish aquarium - they are much more sensitive to being shocked than we are.